# Handling Android back button in mobile site without using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cordova

I need to intercept Android back button event using simple Javascript(if it is possible),

I am having a mobile site where I want to alert the user and close the entire site on click of the back button at any part of my site, I do not need to navigate back of my history

Note: I don't want to include Phonegap support in my site.

Any ideas will be great!

**Edit :**
I also used

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Do you want to exit?";
};
```

This also does not help my situation, because it will be called on unload of the url, I am navigating page to page using div's using #ID  (`using Jquery Mobile <div data-role="page"></div>`)

So I strictly want to get an event on click of the Android Back button

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect that event without some native Java code so you'll have to either listen for the hashchange event coupled with a history stack to detect when the user goes back or use Phonegap. If you need to do something before the user goes back then your only option is some native code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching the `<body onunload=""\>` event? You could probably do an `window.close` in there to prevent the history from being called.

Comment: My navigation is not page to page, its div to div (Whole code is in one html file)

Answer (score 0):

Try window.onpopstate

```
window.onpopstate = function (evt) {              
    if (isAndroid()) {   
        // Android hack. After printing location and state, I can read the state. Not before.
        var triggerCheck = "location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(evt.state);
        //check evt.state if its previous url or not then do your thing   
    }  
};
```

Whats important is try to keep track where you at with the evt.state.
It seems to work fine for me.